# Resources for precision aiming, trying to aim camera long distance

Tags: control, precise-positioning

I'm looking for resources online regarding precision aiming of a camera at a target that is far away. I'm a neophyte here, and I was hoping to see what kind of mechanical designs people have had and what kind of problems they've run into along the way.
The obvious thing that comes to mind for me is manipulating the gear ratio so that the farther gear rotates very slowly and can have tiny angle changes for precise aiming, but I want to see other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing here is a "pan-tilt" or "pan-tilt-zoom" camera, sometimes abbreviated 'PTZ' cameras. What these all basically do is have a motor to rotate some platform, and then another motor to point the camera up and down. This provides enough degrees of freedom to look around wherever the camera is mounted.

But you're asking specifically about precision. You're right that a gearing will allow to you trade speed for smaller movements, but we can do better. Here are some things to consider:

- With every gearing, you're introducing potential for slop (look into "[backlash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlash_(engineering))" for more information on this). So you may quickly get diminishing returns on gearing, but there are techniques to reduce/eliminate backlash: spring loaded systems can be used to reduce backlash, and harmonic/strain wave gears don't have backlash problems (in theory).
- Your gearing is only as good as your motors. Something like a hobby servo motor will jitter, but stepper motors can step and hold to a specific point. You *can* use microstepping with a servo but I would hesitate to trust the precision there.
- Your precision depends on knowing which way you're pointing. Encoders offer the best precision here, but they are digital and so have a finite resolution.
- Instead of gearing, you could use a timing belt (the belts that have teeth), something like a miniature extra light series belt (MXL). This will reduce backlash substantially at a lower cost and weight than precision gearboxes.

With that in mind, my recommendation would be stepper motors in a pan/tilt configuration, geared down using timing belts, and with encoders on the shaft of the pan/tilt mechanisms to ensure an accurate understanding of where the device is pointing.

Comment: I've never heard of encoders before. Are they a component external to the motor? Sounds like it. Also, are they redundant (a little bit) to servo motors?

Comment: A motor encoder is a device that sends electrical pulses while the motor moves, allowing you to record the specific degree that the motor moves to. They aren't redundant to a servo motor because they don't perform motion, they record it: servo motors often rely on motor encoders to operate (cheap servos often use potentiometers, which are much less accurate).